# Create a couchdb view of combined delta changes

Tags: couchdb, delta

I looking at using a "everything is a delta" on one type of doc in couch. How do I create a view to allow me to view the combined data?

For example if I have a user doc:

```
{_id: timosolo, name:"Tim", age:30}
```

and 2 transaction deltas:

```
{user_id: timosolo, name:"Timothy", datetime:"2017/01/02 11:11:11"}
{user_id: timosolo, name:"Timo",    datetime:"2017/01/01 11:11:11"}
```

How do I create a couchdb view (or list?) that takes the last change to give me:

```
{_id: timosolo, name:"Timothy", age:30}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would write a *reduce* function to do this. The point of a reduce function is to combine multiple results into one single result (e.g. sum, max, average, etc.).

There is a fairly good explanation [here](http://www.ramblingincode.com/building-a-couchdb-reduce-function/) of how to write your own reduce function.